# Write Function in C

Tags: c, function

The Question is:
Write a function which takes a sorted list and groups equal values into a group(a list) and therefore returns a list of lists

example:

`group([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]) == [ [1, 1, 1,], [2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4], [5] ]`

& what i did is

```
#include<stdio.h>
void group(int a[],int len);

int main(void)
{
int i,len;
int a[10]={1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5};
len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
group(a,len);
}

void group(int a[],int len)
{
int i,k=0;
//len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

int b[len];
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    int j=0;
    while(a[i]==a[i+1])
    {
        b[j]=a[i];
        i++;
        j++;

    }
    b[j]=a[i];

    printf("[");
    while(j>=0)
    {
        printf("%d,",b[j]);
        j--;
    }
    printf("],");
}
}
```

Here the problem I'm getting is "How to get the size of array from main to group function"

Edit: I edited & getting the result like
[1,1,1,],[2,2,],[3,],[4,4,4,],[5,],

But i have a doubt that "this code is really satisfying the question or not?"

Comment: Guys, this is a scope issue.

Comment: @ameyCU, no, `int a[]` decays into a pointer.

Comment: @AlterMann  Hmm , I wondering about that .

Comment: @ameyCU: [Take a look](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-sizof-operator-with-array-paratmeters/)

Comment: @AlterMann  yes  I tried that . You were correct . My bad .

Comment: You shouldn't modify your code after an answer has been posted

Comment: @psychedelic_alex: agreed, but i don't think my edit still satisfying the question.(In the question the function takes only list as a parameter, but in my program I have taken two arguments)

Comment: `returns a list of lists`

Comment: It is not possible to know the size of the array in the function side in c. So What about using a linked list as a list instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
    int value;
    struct list *next;
} List;

typedef struct llist {//list of list
    List *list;
    struct llist *next;
} LList;

List *make_list_from_array(int len, int a[len]);
LList *group(List *aList);
void print_list(List *aList);
void print_llist(LList *aLList);
void free_list(List *aList);
void free_llist(LList *aLList);

int main(void){
    int len, a[] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5};
    len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);

    List *aList = make_list_from_array(len, a);
    print_list(aList);puts("");

    LList *aLList = group(aList);
    print_llist(aLList);puts("");

    free_llist(aLList);

    return 0;
}

List *make_list_from_array(int len, int a[len]){
    List dummy_head = {0, NULL}, *curr;
    curr = &dummy_head;
    for(int i=0; i < len; ++i){
        List *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        node->value = *a++;
        node->next = NULL;
        curr = curr->next = node;
    }
    return dummy_head.next;
}

LList *group(List *aList){
//aList : sorted list 
//The original list(aList) is destroyed(to be divided).
    LList dummy_head = {NULL, NULL}, *curr;
    curr = &dummy_head;

    List *prev_node = NULL, *curr_node;
    while(aList){
        LList *llist_new;
        if(prev_node == NULL || prev_node->value != aList->value){
            if(prev_node)
                prev_node->next = NULL;//cut list

            llist_new = malloc(sizeof(*llist_new));
            llist_new->next = NULL;
            curr = curr->next = llist_new;

            curr_node = llist_new->list = aList;
        } else {
            curr_node = curr_node->next = aList;
        }
        prev_node = aList;
        aList = aList->next;
    }
    return dummy_head.next;
}

void print_list(List *aList){
    putchar('[');
    while(aList){
        printf("%d", aList->value);
        if(aList->next)
            printf(", ");
        aList = aList->next;
    }
    putchar(']');
}

void print_llist(LList *aLList){
    putchar('[');
    while(aLList){
        print_list(aLList->list);
        if(aLList->next)
            printf(", ");
        aLList = aLList->next;
    }
    putchar(']');

}
void free_list(List *aList){
    while(aList){
        List *temp = aList->next;
        free(aList);
        aList = temp;
    }
}
void free_llist(LList *aLList){
    while(aLList){
        LList *temp = aLList->next;
        free_list(aLList->list);
        aLList = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're gonna post all this code without even an explanation?

Comment: It is a common linked list. There is nothing special part in its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass it as an argument to the `group` function.

```
void group(int a[], int len)
```

and calculate the length in `main` where the variable is in scope.

Comment: thats really superfluent since C supports this natively with the `sizeof` operator

Comment: @specializt: You cannot use `sizeof` in the function. The array isn't visible there.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: the given question/format says the function will take only one argument that to it should be list only.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I edited the program and it was giving result but i think it's not appropriate for the question.